# Does the 'Improve' button instantly accept/reject an edit?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits, edits

As a 2k user over on SO, I've noticed that in the Edit queue, there is a button - <kbd>Improve</kbd>. When I click this button and make an edit to the edit, the original edit seems to be instantly accepted or rejected.

Is this the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, because you as a privileged user take full responsibility for it.

Ticking or unticking the helpful checkbox determines whether or not the original suggestion is rejected or accepted. It does not change the fact that the (improved) edit will be made instantly.

Comment: Even if I tick the 'edit was helpful' check box?

Comment: That only decides whether or not the suggested edit is accepted for the user suggesting it.

Comment: @Undo If you say the edit was helpful, Community will approve it. Otherwise, Community will reject it.